# concatenating Columns and displaying in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table containing two columns (First name and Last name) i need a query or PL/Sql script which concat these two string and display the output in the form of initcap()
eg First_name    Last_name
   Ramesh        Pawar

Output should be **Rameshpawar** (p should be in small case)

Comment: Did you try looking in the [SQL language reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/index.htm)? The index has entries for the `concat()` function, the concatenation operator, and the `initcap()` function. And they all have examples.

Comment: `INITCAP()` will not do what the OP wants if there are non-alphanumeric characters in either name (i.e. "Liam O'Brien" or "Bob Smith-Jones")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you want something like this?

```
select First_name || Lower(Last_name) from table_name;
```

Comment: This answer assumes that first names are all in the required format - if they are not then it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef092/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( First_Name, Last_Name ) AS
          SELECT 'Ramesh', 'Pawar' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'BOB', 'SmItH-JoNeS' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'liam', 'O''Brien' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

If all there are no non-alphanumeric characters in the names then you can use `INITCAP`:

```
SELECT INITCAP( First_Name || Last_Name ) AS Name
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef092/1/0)**:

```
|           NAME |
|----------------|
|    Rameshpawar |
| Bobsmith-Jones |
|    Liamo'Brien |
```

**Query 2**:

However, from the results above, you can see that it doesn't work if you have a double-barrelled name; in this case you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT UPPER( SUBSTR( First_Name || Last_Name, 1, 1 ) ) || LOWER( SUBSTR( First_Name || Last_Name, 2 ) ) AS Name
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef092/1/1)**:

```
|           NAME |
|----------------|
|    Rameshpawar |
| Bobsmith-jones |
|    Liamo'brien |
```

**Query 3**:

If the `First_Name` column is non-null then you can simplify it to:

```
SELECT UPPER( SUBSTR( First_Name, 1, 1 ) ) || LOWER( SUBSTR( First_Name || Last_Name, 2 ) ) AS Name
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef092/1/2)**:

```
|           NAME |
|----------------|
|    Rameshpawar |
| Bobsmith-jones |
|    Liamo'brien |
```